# Is there a simple way to have Mechanize get all the components of a webpage?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

It's my understanding that when I do:

```
agent = Mechanize.New
page = agent.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

Mechanize will make an `HTTP` `GET` request for the `text/html`. However when I navigate to a webpage such as Stackoverflow.com in a full web browser (like Chrome/Firefox) the browser reads in the HTML page and makes subsequent `GET` requests for the associated CSS, images, JavaScript, etc.

I can imagine parsing the initial HTML returned by Mechanize and identifying any CSS, images, etc., and making subsequent requests, but is there an easier way of having Mechanize automatically grab all, or a specified group, perhaps just the images of the associated components of a web page?

Comment: In order to give a helpful answer, it would be good to know what your ultimate goal is. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: One goal is to have Mechanize _look_ and _behave_ more like a full web browser from the perspective of the web server.

Comment: Then you should look into a headless browser like phantomjs!

Comment: Mechanize doesn't have any capability for parsing JavaScript, unlike a browser, so Mechanize won't be the right tool if there is any dynamic HTML changing the page in a significant way. Mechanize only sees the page as the server sends it, not as JavaScript could modify it.

Answer (score 1):

No, Mechanize won't do that. Besides, what would be the point of Mechanize retrieving non-text content it can't parse?

Instead, identify the parts you want, and use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), [Open-URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), or any of the other HTTP-based tools to retrieve the content and save it to disk.

Actually, unless I needed Mechanize to navigate through some forms first, or maintain sessions, I'd write a small Ruby script that uses Nokogiri to pull out the needed elements. If you have to use Mechanize for the initial navigation, it'll load Nokogiri automatically to handle its DOM parsing, so piggy-back on the Mechanize page it can give you, which is a Nokogiri::HTML document. Search through the related links on the right for more information.

Comment: I can think of lots of reasons to use mechanize over all the libs you mentioned. Needing sessions is the most obvious one.

Comment: Yes, maintaining a session is another reason to use Mechanize. If a site doesn't need those though, I wouldn't pull in Mechanize.

Comment: I would. Mechanize is the one that I can always count on to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the `Mechanize::PluggableParser`s that are available. One of them probably does what you want.